# limit filter results?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a game model that hasMany messages. To keep them synced in real time I use a computed property like this:

```
gameMessages: function () {
    var gameId, messages;
    gameId = this.get('id');

    return this.get('store').filter('message', function (message) {
        return (message.get('game.id') === gameId);
    });
}.property('messages'),
```

How can I limit the amount of messages it's returning? I only want to show the 10 newest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a dozen ways you can accomplish this, a simple way that doesn't break the filter

```
gameMessages: function () {
    var gameId, messages, count = 0;
    gameId = this.get('id');


    return this.get('store').filter('message', function (message) {
        return (message.get('game.id') === gameId) && count++ < 10;
    });
}.property('id'),
```

You could also create a computed property that returns 10

```
gameMessages: function () {
    var gameId, messages;
    gameId = this.get('id');


    return this.get('store').filter('message', function (message) {
        return (message.get('game.id') === gameId);
    });
}.property('id'),

top10GameMessages: function(){
  return this.get('gameMessages').toArray().slice(0,1)
}.property('gameMessages.[]')
```

Also, I'm not sure why your computed property was dependent on `messages` I didn't see any property names `messages` being used in the CP.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your second example worked (after some changes specific to my situation), I didn't know about the `toArray()` method.
It's depended on `messages` because I keep getting new messages (via websockets)

Comment: I like the count++ solution. To speed it up you can also check the count on the front end `return count < 10 && (message.get('game.id') === gameId) && count++ < 10;`.  I am using this for a regex comparison on a pretty large data set and it sped up the search considerably.